# What is the algorithmic difference between math.ceil() and round() when trailing decimal points are >= 0.5 in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math

What is the algorithmic difference between math.ceil() and round() when trailing decimal points are >= 0.5 in Python 3?

For example,

```
round(9.5) = 10
round(9.67) = 10
math.ceil(9.5) = 10
math.ceil(9.5) = 10
```

Comment: Try an input of `8.5`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson why does that happen? floating point binary issue?

Comment: @Skyler: No: it's an explicit choice in Python 3 to round halfway cases to the nearest *even* number. That's the default IEEE 754 rounding mode (roundTiesToEven), and Python isn't alone in using it by default for rounding.

Comment: This is a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48723589/2419789) for the same topic. It explains both functions plus talks about rounding facts with references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round),

> [...] if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even
>   choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and
>   round(1.5) is 2).

However, `math.ceil` will always "round" up. I.e. the smallest integer greater than or equal to the input.

Moreover, `round` and `math.ceil` differ greatly when executing on negative numbers.

```
>>> math.ceil(-2.8)
-2
>>> round(-2.8)
-3
```