# Why do round() and math.ceil() give different values for negative numbers in Python 3?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Why do round() and math.ceil() give different values for negative numbers in Python 3?

For example,

```
round(-5.5) = -6
round(-5.7) = -6
math.ceil(-5.5) = -5
math.ceil(-5.7) = -5
```

Comment: Because rounding and the math ceiling are *different operations*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functions execute different mathematical operations:

- `round()` rounds a float value to the *nearest integer*. If either of the two integers on either side are equal distance apart, the *even number* is picked.

  Here, the *nearest* integer is always `-6`; for `-5.5` the nearest even integer is `-6`, not `-5`.
- `math.ceil()` returns the smallest integer *greater than or equal* to the float value.

  Here, the next integer *greater* than the inputs is always `-5` (remember that negative numbers *decrease* away from zero).

I think the biggest confusion you have comes from the *even rounding rule*. Had you picked `-4.5`, you'd have seen `round()` return `-4`:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(-4.5)
-4
>>> round(-4.5)
-4
```

From the [`round()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both `round(0.5)` and `round(-0.5)` are `0`, and `round(1.5)` is `2`).

Rounding half to the nearest integers always has to break the tie *somehow*, and different programming languages don't always agree on how to do this, the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) defines 5 different methods. Python 3 uses the IEEE 754 default and rounds [halves to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), because this method has the advantage that it is free of sign bias and in reasonable distributions of numbers will result in the same average values.

Comment: I thought it rounded away from 0, so `round(-0.5)` is `-1` or is that Python 2 only?

Comment: To be clear, three of the five IEEE 754 rounding modes are directed, so ties aren't a special case for those modes. IEEE 754 only defines two round-to-nearest rounding modes (and only one of those is _required_ for binary floating-point types; the other is optional). Okay, I'll stop nitpicking now.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: well, you make an explicit choice about the direction to round to in those cases; hardcoding a direction is also a solution to the tie. :-)

Comment: I'm still horrified that JavaScript's round-to-nearest doesn't follow *either* of the IEEE 754 round-to-nearest modes, though. (It always rounds ties towards +infinity.)

Answer (score 0):

Ceil(argument) will return closest biggest whole number if the argument is a float, -5 is BIGGER than -6. As for round() please view python's doc. I believe its pretty well explained.